# Translate course name in certificate field in Moodle

Tags: php, moodle

Certificates must be issued in two languages. {mlang} is used elsewhere on the site.
how to access {mlang} filter in php code? Or is there another way to translate?

I'm thinking about changing plugins Workplace certificate manager or Workplace course certificate.
If you can tell me where to start?

Comment: Is it 2 certificates per user? In 2 specific languages? Or 1 certificate per user in their language?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Moodle Docs](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Filters#Trying_out_your_filter),

> Filters are applied to all text that is printed with the output functions `format_text()`, and, if you have turned on that option, `format_string()`.

If you need to change php code to include filters, you need to pass the required string as a parameter to any of the two functions in the quote above.